# trying to open a .txt file but keep getting error message

Tags: python, file

This is my code to opening the file; I would like it to contain a name and a figure:

```
file_n = "Class_" + str(num_class) + ".txt"
file = open(file_n,"r")
string = file.read()
file.close()
```

and this is the error message I keep getting and I can't work out how to fix it:

```
file = open(file_n,"r")
```

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Class_2.txt'

Could someone please tell me why this happening and the solution to it?
im still very confused 
this is my whole code:

```
import random

import json

score = 0

turn = 1

turn = turn + 1

name = raw_input("what is your name?")

num_class = input("What class are you in? (1,2,3)")

print ("hello "+name+" have fun and good luck!")

for turn in range(10):


    randnum_1 = random.randint(1,10)
    randnum_2 = random.randint(1,10)
    operators = ["+", "-", "*"]
    operator_picked = operators[random.randint(0,2)]
    human_answer = raw_input("What is " + str(randnum_1) +" "+ operator_picked +" " + str(randnum_2) + "?")
    correct_answer = str((eval(str(randnum_1) + operator_picked + str(randnum_2))))


    if correct_answer == human_answer :
        score = score+1
        print ("Correct!")

    else:
        print ("Incorrect!" +"The correct answer is " + str(correct_answer))


print("\nYour score was " + str(score)+ "/10")


file_name = ("Class_" + str(num_class) + ".txt")

file = open(file_n,"r")

string = file.read()

file.close()

dict = {}
```

Comment: Looks like the error is happening because "Class_2.txt" is not the name of an existing file or directory. Try a different name.

Comment: Most likely, your file does not exist in the directory that the code is looking at. The directory your code is considering is the directory where your first python script was launched.

Comment: Check your current directory
    import os
    print(os.getcwd())

Comment: or provide an absolute path to the file

Comment: thanks for your help, im still confused though so i posted my whole code and would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure that your Python code lies in the same directory with your txt file.**

So it should be like this:
[image]

Of course the two files can be in different directories, but then you should provide the relevant, or absolute, path of the txt file to your code.

---

As 1001010 stated, you could check your current directory by doing:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? If I said something wrong I would like to fix it, for future readers, *please*.

Comment: sorry im new to this i didnt mean it ill try and change it

Comment: That's a good start @joel, check the answers and accept the best.

Comment: would you mind helping me slightly further as i havent solved the problem. thanks

Comment: Are you in Linux @joel? Did you do what my answer says?

Comment: i have no idea where to put your answer, i updated my question using my whole code, this might make it easier to answer. @gsamaras

Comment: @joel your python code is in a file that inside a directory, correct?

Comment: In that directory @joel, do you have the txt file you are looking for? eg. Class_2.txt

Comment: No @joel. You want to open a file and then read from it. So, before running the code, you need to create the .txt file manually, by yourself, like if you weren't a programmer. Create that file, fill it, save it, by using an editor (gedit for example, notepad or something) and then run your code.

Comment: Are you in windows? Or Linux @joel?

Comment: i am in idle using a mac @gsamaras

Comment: Use TextEdit. Fill in the new document with the data you want and then save it in the name you expect it, "Class_2.txt". Of course, save it in the same directory as the Python file. @joel

Comment: but the name the user would save it under could be anything i dont understand @gsamaras

Comment: my code is quiz taken by students who enter their name and the name of that student and the score they received should be written on the file and available to see in a dictionary format which i am not sure how to do either @gsamaras

Comment: Well @joel you should try to work out your approach. You cannot read from a file that is not created! Take the input from user, then write it to the file, which you know the name, for example "myfile.txt". Then you can do whatever you want with the data. However, if that doesn't work, post a new question.

Comment: You are welcome @joel, do not forget to accept an answer. I will upvote since you are a new member here and show dedication, but think clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like Kevin and Flavian mentioned the directory of Class_2.txt is most likely not the directory where your script is located.

```
file_n = "/ActualDirectory/ofFile/Class_" + str(num_class) + ".txt"
```